# File sorting program makes nested directories if executed again

Tags: python, shutil, file-sorting

When the code is run for the first time everything works perfectly but when i execute it a second time the already present directories are nested and the code stops after the error that it cannot put the folder in the same named folder

```
import os
import shutil

path = "your_path"



file_names = os.listdir(path)

folder_names=["image files","text files","archives","setups","word files","pdf files","other documents","miscellaneous"]

for i in range(len(folder_names)):
    if not os.path.exists(path+folder_names[i]):
        os.mkdir(path+folder_names[i])
    else:
        break

for file in file_names:
    if ".txt" in file and not os.path.exists(path + "text files/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "text files/" + file)
    elif ".pdf" in file and not os.path.exists(path + "pdf files/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "pdf files/" + file)
    elif ".exe" in file and not os.path.exists(path + "setups/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "setups/" + file)
    elif any(ext in file for ext in [".zip", ".rar"]) and not os.path.exists(path + "archives/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "archives/" + file)
    elif any(ext in file for ext in [".docx", ".doc"]) and not os.path.exists(path + "word files/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "word files/" + file)
    elif any(ext in file for ext in [".jpg",".gif", ".jpeg", ".png"]) and not os.path.exists(path + "image files/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "image files/" + file)
    elif any(ext in file for ext in [".pptx", ".xlsx", ".csv"]) and not os.path.exists(path + "image files/" + file):
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "other documents/" + file)
    else:
        shutil.move(path + file, path + "miscellaneous/" + file)
```

The following code after executing the second time stops after the following error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 563, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/miscellaneous' -> 'C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/miscellaneous/miscellaneous'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\file_sorter\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    shutil.move(path + file, path + "miscellaneous/" + file)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 572, in move
    " '%s'." % (src, dst))
shutil.Error: Cannot move a directory 'C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/miscellaneous' into itself 'C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/miscellaneous/miscellaneous'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run this script, the folders from `folder_names` (likely) don't exist, so they're not in `file_names`.
The second time though, they do, so they're treated like any other files, which means the `else:` part of the script will try to move them into `miscellaneous`.

What you want to do is exclude these folders from the treatment; you can do that either in the final `else:` part of the script, by replacing the `else:` block with

```
elif file not in folder_names:
    shutil.move(path + file, path + "miscellaneous/" + file)
```

or at the start of the script, for example by defining `file_names` thus:

```
folder_names=["image files","text files","archives","setups","word files","pdf files","other documents","miscellaneous"]

file_names = set(os.listdir(path)) - set(folder_names)
```